# Powershell trouble with module creation

Tags: windows, powershell, module, scripting

I'm trying to create module with default values, looks like this:

```
function Send-Mail ($EmailTo = "all@example.com" , $Body = "Warning! Technical Maintance today", $Subject = "*** Warning! ***")
{
$EmailFrom = "it@example.com"
$SMTPServer = "mail.example.com" 
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587) 
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true 
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("it", "Hjcnthv1"); 
$SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)
}

Export-ModuleMember -Function 'Send-Mail'
```

Then I'm trying to use it:

```
Import-Module '\\dc01\scripts$\_server\Send-Mail.psm1'
Send-Mail user@example.com "Text" "Subject"
```

But I recieve error:

```
Exception calling "Send" with "4" argument(s): "Failure sending mail."
At \\dc01\scripts$\_server\Send-Mail.psm1:14 char:1
+ $SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I wonder if the brackets in the Send call are the problem. I know you should not have them for PowerShell function calls as they convert all parameters into one object if you put them in brackets, and thus are passed in as a single parameter. I'm just not sure if that's the same with method calls to .NET objects.

Comment: So basically, I'm saying try this: `$SMTPClient.Send $EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body `

Comment: The brackets aren't a problem. Method calls expect an array-based argument list.

Comment: You really should check the documentation before using methods. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swas0fwc(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your module creation is fine the error is down to your function not working correctly. Try creating the message object first before sending.

```
$msg = New-object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage -ArgumentList @($EmailFrom,$EmailTo,$Subject,$Body)
$SMTPClient.Send($msg)
```

You have also selected to enable SSL without giving your SMTP client a certificate `$SMTPClient.ClientCertificates`. As you are supplying credentials you may not require SSL so you can delete the line `$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true`.

On a side note you could add the following to disposing of your object after use.

```
$msg.Dispose()
$SMTPClient.Dispose()
```

Comment: @user3301252 if this question has help or answered your question please accept or upvote it.